# How can make field optional in django rest nested serializer

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have this code

```
# Models

class Parent(models.Model):
        something = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Child1(models.Model):
        thing = models.BooleanField()
        parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent)

    # Serializers

class Child1Serializer(BaseSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child1
        fields = ('thing', 'parent')

class Child2Serializer(BaseSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Child2
        fields = ('thing', 'parent')

class ParentSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    sisters = Child1Serializer(many=True)
    cousins = Child2Serializer(many=True)
```

Now when i do post in Child1 and then pass parent in json and everything works

But when i want to write nested serializer of parent so that child also gets created automatically

```
"sisters": [
   {
      "thing": "tom"
   }
],
"cousins": [
   {
      "thing": "mike"
   },
]
```

Then i don't need to pass parent as i will manually assign in create method

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    sisters = validated_data.pop('sisters')
    parent = Parent.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for obj in sisters:
        Child1.objects.create(parent=parent, **obj)
    return parent
```

The problem is when i post parent then i get validation error that in sister , that parent is required

Comment: try using django clever-select

Comment: did you pop `cousins` from `validated_data` before creating the parent?

Comment: @Anush no , it was only example

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't need the `parent` field in your nested serializer. It's redundant with the data sent to the API.

Comment: you mean i don't need parent in child serilaizer?

Comment: Exactly. It's redondant with the parent item, isn't it ?

Comment: Note that by writing "Child1.objects.create(parent=parent, **obj)" you already provide the parent. There's no reason obj which comes from the nested child serializer also brings it. Plus Python will complain about having twice the same argument.

Comment: you are right in that . But your point is valid if I am POSTing PARENT object to create CHILD as well . BUT if i only post child then parent won't be in the validated data , as serializer will remove it  if i don't have it defined in fields

Comment: Not what your code shows (parent = Parent.objects.create(**validated_data))

Comment: Then i need to define create method on every child serializer as well because currently i only had it overridden in parent serializer

Comment: The children serializer's create/update aren't called. The entire code should go  to the parent's create/update